# Write a number and a unit in a single word

Tags: java

I am trying to write a formula in Java, using `Javax.units` API to write a number and a unit into a single word. Here is my implementation so far.

```
Unit mm = SI.MILLI(SI.METER);
Unit mm2 = mm.pow(2);
Unit unit = SI.NEWTON.divide(mm2);
System.out.println(formula); //output = N/mm^2

int i = 1234;
int singleWord = 1234*N/mm^2
     or 
Unit singleWord = 1234*N/mm^2 // is it possible to write something like this?
```

Please Note: I am not looking for String format, because I am going to use "singleWord" in further my calculations.

Comment: Can you first convert it to String object and then split it using * and then use just the numerical part of it in further steps? That would work. If you really wanted to get into it, you could create a custom class or a method that would do it behind the scenes for you.

Comment: @Sunil: i was thinking of doing this in your way,just wondering if there is an alternative. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Ok.. I'll post it then. For at least the points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you first convert it to String object and then split it using * and then use just the numerical part of it in further steps? That would work. If you really wanted to get into it, you could create a custom class or a method that would do it behind the scenes for you.